# Manipulate a .csv file with just one row (R Packages suggestions for data manipulation?)

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm working with new data involving a .csv file but with just 1 row, I have no headers and the data looks like this:

As you can see in the next example the data is comma separated and it has no rows

```
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can put that in a data frame and if there is any R package suggestions for data manipulation, because I'm learning since a while R and data manipulations is my weakest point.

The idea is to:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,
```

Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = read.table(text = 'UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3,UserName,Date,Time,Var1,Var2,Var3', sep = ",")
result = as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(unlist(input)), ncol = 6, byrow = T))

result
#         V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
# 1 UserName Date Time Var1 Var2 Var3
# 2 UserName Date Time Var1 Var2 Var3
# 3 UserName Date Time Var1 Var2 Var3
# 4 UserName Date Time Var1 Var2 Var3
# 5 UserName Date Time Var1 Var2 Var3
# 6 UserName Date Time Var1 Var2 Var3
```

I'll leave the renaming of columns to you.

Comment: instead of using `read.table` then `unlist` and `as.character` use `input = 
 scan(text=...,what='character', sep=",")`